# Find a counter example to majorization theory

Tags: inequality, positive-semidefinite

Theorem: Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix with diagonal elements $d=[d_1\cdots d_n]'$ and eigenvalues $\lambda=[\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n]'$, where $d_1\geq\cdots\geq d_n$ and $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$, then we have

\begin{equation}
d_n\geq\lambda_n,\\
d_{n-1}d_n\geq\lambda_{n-1}\lambda_n,\\
\vdots\\
\prod_{i=1}^nd_i\geq\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i.
\end{equation}

As you can see this theorem only works one way. I want to understand why the other way around doesn't work, i.e.: if the above inequalities hold, why not always there exists positive semi-definite $X$ with diagonal elements $d=[d_1\cdots d_n]'$ and eigenvalues $\lambda=[\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n]'$.

The above theorem is related to theory of product majorization. I went though some books related to theory of majorization, but couldn't find a hint. Can anyone suggest me a route to try or provide some counter-example that will help me to understand the issue? Assume $\lambda_i\geq1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Do you additionally require $\sum d_i = \sum \lambda_i$ in the counterexample? Otherwise take $d = \mathbf 1_n$ and $\lambda = 0_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some part. I don't require $\sum d_i=\sum \lambda_i$, but I assume   $\lambda_i\geq1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Are you sure the other way around doesn't work, or are you assuming that it doesn't work?

Comment: @N.S. I saw this theorem in research paper, it is not if and only if condition. That is why I assume other way doesn't work.

Comment: @Lee Even with that condition, you can find counterexamples, because for any matrix, $\sum d_i = \sum \lambda_i$. So for instance, take $d_1 = \cdots = d_n = 2$ and $\lambda_1 = \cdots = \lambda_n = 1$. Then all your conditions are satisfied but obviously there is no matrix with diagonal entries $d_i$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

Comment: So the interesting question, I think, is whether for every $\{d_i\}$, $\{\lambda_i\}$ satisfying $$d_k \ge 0,\ \lambda_k \ge 0,\ \prod_{i = k}^n d_i \ge \prod_{i = k}^n \lambda_i,\quad k = 1, \ldots, n,$$ $$\sum_{i = 1}^n d_i = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i,$$ there exists a p.s.d. Hermitian matrix $A$ with $d_i$ as its diagonal entries and $\lambda_i$ as its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Lee That's not necessarily true.. It could mean that the authors don't know the answer, or don't care about the answer. The latest could be the case, especially since the direct implication has nice applications, while the converse doesn't seem to have any interesting consequence.